# Exercise showing that $\nabla f(r) = \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}r}\cdot \frac{\underline{r}}{r} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Let

$$\underline{r}(x,y,z) := \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

be a vector field in Cartesian coordinates. The length $r$ of the vector $\underline{r}$ is

$$r = \sqrt{x^2+ y^2 + z^2} $$

Show that

$$\nabla f(r) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}r}\cdot \dfrac{\underline{r}}{r} $$

---

This is an exercise in preparation for a test. Here's what I have tried to do using chain rule:

$$\begin{split} 
\nabla f(r) &= \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x(f(r))\\ \partial_y (f(r))\\ \partial_z(f(r))\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x(f(r)) \cdot \dfrac{x}{r}\\ \partial_y (f(r)) \cdot \dfrac{y}{r}\\ \partial_z(f(r))\cdot \dfrac{z}{r}\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{split}$$

So if $$\partial_x(f(r)) = \partial_y(f(r)) = \partial_z(f(r)) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}r}\ $$ was a scalar, I would be done. However I don't know this would be the case or if I have applied the chain rule correctly.

How do I continue from here, or how should I start in the first place to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't applied the chain rule correctly. Doing so gives you the result pretty easily. The correct chain rule is

$$\nabla f(r):=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\partial_x(f(r)) \\
\partial_y(f(r))\\
\partial_z(f(r))
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{df}{dr}\cdot\partial_x(r) \\
\frac{df}{dr}\cdot\partial_y(r)\\
\frac{df}{dr}\cdot\partial_z(r)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

All that's left now is to compute these partial derivatives, which you seem to have already done.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why is $\partial_x (f(r)) = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}r} \cdot \partial_x(r)$ when the chain rule is applied correctly?

Comment: That is the correct chain rule. What makes you think it's different? If $r$ was just a function of $x$, would you agree that $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dx}$? The version I used just replaced total derivatives in $x$ by partial ones. Sure, this doesn't quite prove it, if you only know the one-variable version of the chain rule, but it should be intuitive, since what the partial derivative does is ignore other dependencies and kind of treat the function as a one-variable function. As an alternative, you could just apply the general version of the chain rule, as @paulinho explains

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use the notation $\vec{r} = (x, y, z)$. We are ultimately trying to find $\nabla f(r) = \nabla f(g(\vec{r}))$ where $g(r) = \|\vec{r}\|$. Now we know from the chain rule that $\nabla f(g(\vec{r}))=\frac{df}{dg(\vec{r})} \nabla g(\vec{r})$, which gives the desired answer.

When remembering the chain rule, it's often helpful to think of the [derivative *matrix*](https://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix). The chain rule says that (using the notation in the link) $D(f(g(\vec{x}))) = Df(g(\vec{x})) \cdot Dg(\vec{x})$, where the dot symbolizes matrix multiplication. Note that for this matrix multiplication to be well-defined, we must have the composition to be well-defined. In the special case that we have some $h(\vec{x}): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, we use the shorthand $Dh(\vec{x}) = \nabla h(\vec{x})$.